# Using Charts control VisualStudio2010 -WPF The Toolbox Controls Installer must be installed before running this installer

Tags: installation, toolbox

I need to display charts in my WPF application.
I read somewhere that Mschart.exe and mschart visual studio addon has to be installed to make the charts control usable.
I installed MScharts.exe and it installed succesfully but when i run MSchart visual studio addon it ends up with this error

"The Toolbox Controls Installer must be installed before running this installer."

No help somewhere, from where can i get the Tool box installer.

Any help will certainly appreciated..

i am using Visual studio 2010 on Windows Xp